# Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result()

Tags: mysqli, php

Короче говоря, залил сайт на сервер с ОС Linux, php version 5.3.20. Так вот на сервере не работает  метод mysqli_stmt::get_result(). Погуглил - проблема не у меня одного (тысячи их). Необходим драйвер mysqInd. Короче, в репозиториях менять что-то надо и т.д. и т.п. в общем мозгопотрошилка.  По-моему это глупо,что на серверах нет драйверов. Бред какой-то. Теперь что - отказываться от методов bind_param, prepare и переходить снова на старый древний mysql? Ребята, как с этим бороться?

Comment: используйте bind_result

Comment: @eicto, респект! mysqli_stmt нечто новое для меня, спасибо, теперь разобрался!

Comment: @eicto, не сложно будет подсказать? для метода stmt->result() требуется определенное кол-во переменных для хранения результата запроса. Как быть, если этих переменных при разных запросах разное количество?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php